# std::map<string, class> print the value of the key

Tags: c++, stl

My program is written in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;


    class Details
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    };

    typedef std::map<string, Details> Det;
    Det det;

    Details::Details(int p, int c) {
        x = p;
        y = c;
    }

    int main(){

        det.clear();

        insertNew("test", 1, 2);

        cout << det["test"] << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

I want to print the value of a key with the simplest way. Eg det["test"] fails to compile.
How to I print values (1,2) for (x,y) that correspond to key "test"?

Comment: The above code is full of syntax errors and is not even a valid program. Please give the actual code you couldn't compile.

Comment: You're missing two close parentheses at the end of your code.

Comment: @ybungalobill, we are right. I update my question with actual code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that you have no default or copy constructor in your Obj (you don't have any in the code you posted, but I assume you have one that takes two integers).  You've also got a typo in the catalog.insert() line.  Here is what worked for me, using your code:

```
class Obj {
public:
    Obj() {}
    Obj(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    int x;
    int y; 
   };


int main (int argc, char ** argv) {

    std::map<std::string, Obj> catalog; 
    catalog.insert(std::map<std::string, Obj>::value_type("test", Obj(1,2)));

    std::cout << catalog["test"].x << " " << catalog["test"].y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah you ninja edited me!  :)  You need to either create an operator << as noted in another answer, or access the x, y members.

Comment: Performing `operator[]` multiple times for the same value can severely degrade performance.

Comment: Agreed, as I'm sure converting the same C-string to a std::string over and over does too.  The code was just meant to illustrate accessing the map in a way similar to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Create an `operator<<` for your class `Obj` and then you can do something like `std::cout << catalog["test"];` (I'm assuming that the missing parens in the insert call are just a copy-paste-o).

Answer (score 1):

I've changed a bit your code.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Obj {
    public:
            Obj( int in_x, int in_y ) : x( in_x ), y( in_y )
            {};
            int x;
            int y;
    };

int main()
{
    std::map< string, Obj* > catalog; 
    catalog[ "test" ] = new Obj(1,2);

    for( std::map<string, Obj*>::iterator i=catalog.begin(); i != catalog.end(); ++i )
    {
            cout << "x:" << i->second->x << " y:" << i->second->y << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given these types:

```
class Obj {
    int x;
    int y; };

std::map<string, Obj> catalog;
```

Given a populated `catalog` object:

```
for(auto ob = catalog.begin(); ob != catalog.end(); ++ob)
{
   cout << ob->first << " " << ob->second.x << " " << ob->second.y;
}
```